My Docker container is not connecting with open ai when I run python code
I am trying to create an agent in OPEN AI, that would authenticate with VS code server based on user input. The VS code server is running in docker container docker-vscode-1. I ran following code in docker container:
import os
import requests
import logging
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain_community.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.agents import initialize_agent, Tool
from langchain.agents.agent_types import AgentType
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
load_dotenv()

# Configuration
CODE_SERVER_URL = os.getenv("CODE_SERVER_URL", "http://172.20.0.2:8080")
PASSWORD = os.getenv("CODE_SERVER_PASSWORD", "yourpassword")
LOGIN_URL = f"{CODE_SERVER_URL}/login"
SESSION = requests.Session()
DEBUG = os.getenv("DEBUG", "False").lower() == "true"
OPENAI_API_KEY = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG if DEBUG else logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s"
)


def authenticate():
    """Authenticates with the code-server."""
    if not PASSWORD:
        logging.error("Password not set. Please set the 'CODE_SERVER_PASSWORD' environment variable.")
        return "Password not set."

    try:
        # Get the login page to retrieve CSRF token if needed (optional for code-server)
        response = SESSION.get(LOGIN_URL)
        response.raise_for_status()

        # Post the login credentials
        payload = {"password": PASSWORD}
        auth_response = SESSION.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
        auth_response.raise_for_status()

        # Check if login was successful
        if auth_response.status_code == 200 and "code-server" in auth_response.text:
            logging.info("Authentication successful!")
            return "Authentication successful!"
        else:
            logging.warning("Authentication failed. Check your password or URL.")
            return "Authentication failed. Check your password or URL."

    except Exception as e:
        error_message = f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}"
        logging.error(error_message)
        return error_message


# Define the LangChain agent tools
tools = [
    Tool(
        name="Authenticate with Code-Server",
        func=authenticate,
        description="Authenticate with the VS code-server. \
            This is a one-time action and does not require further input. \
            This action completes immediately."
    )
]

# Initialize the LangChain agent with OpenAI's LLM
def main():
    
    llm = OpenAI(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, temperature=0)

    agent = initialize_agent(
        tools,
        llm,
        agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
        verbose=True
    )

    # Agent loop to take user input
    print("Simple AI Agent is ready! Type 'exit' to quit.")
    while True:
        user_input = input("\nEnter your instruction (type 'exit' to quit): ")
        if user_input.lower() in ["exit", "quit"]:
            print("Goodbye!")
            break

        try:
            # Get the agent's response for a single action
            response = agent.run(user_input)
            # Ensure that no further actions are taken after a single response
            if "Action:" in response:
                print("Ashwani Kumar Shamlodhiya: The AI has finished processing your request.")
            else:
                print(response)
    
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I received following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/coder/project/temp/aiagent-vscode-using-openaiTODO.py", line 113, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/coder/project/temp/aiagent-vscode-using-openaiTODO.py", line 83, in main
    llm = OpenAI(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, temperature=0)
  File "/home/coder/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/_api/deprecation.py", line 216, in warn_if_direct_instance
    return wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/coder/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/load/serializable.py", line 125, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 214, in __init__
    validated_self = self.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pydantic/_internal/_decorators_v1.py", line 148, in _wrapper1
    return validator(values)
  File "/home/coder/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/utils/pydantic.py", line 219, in wrapper
    return func(cls, values)
  File "/home/coder/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_community/llms/openai.py", line 322, in validate_environment
    values["client"] = openai.OpenAI(**client_params).completions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/openai/_client.py", line 123, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 844, in __init__
    self._client = http_client or SyncHttpxClientWrapper(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 742, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'

My operating system is windows. Any suggestions on how can I fix this ?

One solution that worked was downgrading openai and httpx:
 pip install openai==1.55.3 httpx==0.27.2 --force-reinstall --quiet
Run this inside the container
